# How to create a SQL query result from multiple select statements(WITHOUT UNION)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few select statements that when executed alone return what I need.
I want to combine all these select statements into what looks like a normal table.
I tried UNION but get an error that says I need the same number of arguments( column fields obviously),that however is not what I want.
So I tried this(my code so far)

```
SELECT Company_Code FROM Company
UNION
SELECT Founder FROM Company
UNION
SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id) as varchar(5)) as Number_of_LeadManagers
FROM Lead_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Lead_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_SeniorManagers
FROM Senior_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Senior_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_Managers
FROM Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_Employees
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Employee.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
```

This entire statement return everything I want below each other.
Taking my code if each select statement is run alone it return exactly what I want(always return two rows)
What I want is for the final result to Just put all these select statements results next to each other so this will show 2 rows with however many columns was returned by the select statements.

Idea of what I want for clarification
If I execute

```
SELECT Company_Code,Founder FROM Company
```

I get

```
**Result1**
row 1 :  C1 Monika
row 2 :  C2 Samantha
```

(ONLY 2 ROWS ALWAYS)
If I execute

```
   SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id) as varchar(5)) as Number_of_LeadManagers
    FROM Lead_Manager
    LEFT JOIN Company
    ON (Lead_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
    GROUP BY Company.id
```

I get

```
**Result2**
row 1 : 1
row 2 : 1
```

The other select statements are basically the same just using different tables to count from.
All I want is a query that will allow me to put Result1 and Result2 next to each other(as well as the rest of the select results)
Desired final result

```
**Result3**
row 1 : C1 Monika 1
row 2 : C2 Samantha 1
```

PS.Started SQL last week still struggling , this is a homework project by the way.
If my way of thinking is wrong let me know but that is how I see it in my brain and cannot quite figure out how to SQL it ;P

Comment: I'm not sure why you cannot resolve the error.  All the queries have one result, so the only difference is one is returning a VARCHAR.  If you return that as an integer, you should have no error.  If you want results to have integers on all the results, except some records which will be a VARCHAR, you will not be able to write *any* query which does that.

Comment: Do you have example data and what would you like your results to look like? If you only want 2 columns, alias them to the same name, though you may lose some of the context of your data. If use don't expect duplicates across the tables, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Do you want one row of data per `Company_Code`? With a `Founder` and then counts of the various positions?

Comment: What type of SQL Server is it? Version?

Comment: Edited my question for clarity hopefully ahahah.....And Shawn that is exactly what I want my final result to be......SQL Server 2017 Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string column then you need  s string column for each select in union  c

So you just need  cast each count as char  as in the first select

```
SELECT Company_Code FROM Company
UNION
SELECT Founder FROM Company
UNION
SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id) as varchar(5)) as Number_of_LeadManagers
FROM Lead_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Lead_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id) as varchar(5)) as Number_of_SeniorManagers
FROM Senior_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Senior_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id)  as varchar(5)) as Number_of_Managers
FROM Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
UNION
SELECT CAST(COUNT(Company.id) as varchar(5)) as Number_of_Employees
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Employee.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
```

but if you need all the results on the same rows  you could use left join on the subquery

```
SELECT Company_Code , Founder
  , t1.Number_of_LeadManagers
  , t2.Number_of_SeniorManagers
  , t3.Number_of_Managers 
  , t4.Number_of_Employees
FROM Company
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Company.id, COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_LeadManagers
FROM Lead_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company ON Lead_Manager.Companyid = Company.id
GROUP BY Company.id
) t1 on t1.id = company.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  company.id, COUNT(Company.id)  as Number_of_SeniorManagers
FROM Senior_Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Senior_Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
) t2 ON t2.id = company.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT company.id, COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_Managers
FROM Manager
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Manager.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
) t3 ON t3.id = company.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT company.id, COUNT(Company.id) as Number_of_Employees
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Company
ON (Employee.Companyid = Company.id)
GROUP BY Company.id
) t4 ON t4.id = company.id
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189150/discussion-between-moonninja-and-scaisedge).

Comment: SInce you only care about managers assigned to a Company, you can use an `INNER JOIN` on the inner queries. That could make the joined results smaller.

Comment: Also, if you have a Company without any managers in a group, you'll want to check for `NULL` and switch that to a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get all of them on the same row would just be with correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT Company.Company_Code, Company.Founder 
  , (
        SELECT COUNT(Company.id) 
        FROM Lead_Manager
        WHERE Lead_Manager.Companyid = Company.id
    ) AS Number_of_LeadManagers
  , (
        SELECT COUNT(Company.id) 
        FROM Senior_Manager
        WHERE Senior_Manager.Companyid = Company.id
    ) AS Number_of_SeniorManagers
  , (
        SELECT COUNT(Company.id) 
        FROM Manager
        WHERE Manager.Companyid = Company.id
    ) AS Number_of_Managers
  , (
        SELECT COUNT(Company.id) 
        FROM Employee
        WHERE Employee.Companyid = Company.id
    ) AS Number_of_Employees
FROM Company
```

Depending on your data, you may need to further eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shawn.....I didn't know you could use anything like "subqueries" gonna study a bit hahaha it helped me understand above's answer which also helped